# About logical operator && in php

Tags: php

here is the code

```
$a = 2;
$a && $a = 1;

var_dump( $a ); // result 1
```

Why $a is 1?

According to the document, logical operator '&&' has greater precedence than assign operator, it should be interpreted as ($a && $a) = 1, then there should be a syntax error.

Comment: Well, what do you *expect* to happen?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I would have hoped this to give some kind of error!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol As the doc, it should be interpreted as ($a && $a) = 1, then there should be a syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

> **Note:**
>   Although `=` has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: `if (!$a = foo())`, in which case the return value of `foo()` is put into `$a`.

The documentation doesn't specify what rules are followed at this point, but we can infer that your code is equivalent to this:

```
$a && ($a = 1)
```

Because `&&` is "lazy" in that it won't bother evaluating further arguments if it finds one that's false, this means that `$a` will only be set to `1` if it previously held a truthy value (in your case, `2` is truthy). If you had set `$a = 0` then it would have stayed `0`.

Comment: I don't think the "also" quote has any relevance here; evaluation order and precedence are generally unrelated topics.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think it helps emphasise that order of evaluation may not always be exact, but I could be interpreting it wrong.

Comment: Precedence is about how the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) is built.  That 2nd quote is referring to stuff like `a() + b()`; it's not defined whether `a` or `b` is evaluated (i.e. called) first.

Comment: However +1 for the first quote, which explains the behaviour.  (Although it's another example of quite how terribly inconsistent and badly-defined PHP is!)

Comment: I agree with @OliCharlesworth about the quote, but the key is in `"otherwise you would have an invalid left-hand-side for your assignment"`. This is the main reason why it is how it is: It cannot be evaluated in a different order.

Comment: My answer's a bit all over the place, isn't it? XD If one of you can edit it to phrase it better, feel more than welcome to - I suck at explaining sometimes!

Comment: @GolezTrol: Agreed.  But it would be significantly better if the interpreter just threw an error at that point, rather than silently carrying on with behaviour that appears to not be properly defined!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I've attempted an edit to your answer; feel free to revert/modify if that doesn't capture your intent any more.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Much more to-the-point now, but I think the bit about the alternative interpretation being a syntax error might be worth keeping.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I'll leave that decision up to you!  (AFAICS this isn't stated anywhere in the PHP docs, and certainly isn't universally true...)

Answer (score 2):

The way it's written, you're saying the same thing as this

```
$a = 2;
if($a) $a = 1;
```

Since `2` is *something*, it succeeds and changes `$a` to 1.

So why does it do this? You have a statement that `$a = 2`; There's no order of operations here so PHP processes it. The order of operations DOES come into effect on the second statement. Remember, `$a` is SOMETHING, (i.e. truthy). Let's change your code slightly

```
$a = 0;
$a && $a = 1;
echo $a;
```

As you can see, `$a` is now falsy. So the order prevents the script from changing the value and the script outputs `0`

Comment: But as the OP says, `&&` [is supposed to](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) have higher precedence than assignment.  Thus the OP's code should be equivalent to `($a && $a) = 1;`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Does it make any difference that that is not valid code? To me it makes no sense.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Perhaps.  So are the rules for PHP operators "Follow the precedence table, unless that results in something meaningless, in which case, try... something else"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a && $a = 1;
```

is an expression of boolean type. Since `$a` is truthy, the evaluation of the expression continues onto the second part, which is the assignment. As a side effect of the assignment, `$a` now holds `1`.

If `$a` had been 0 in the start, it'd remain 0 in the end, as the evaluation of the expression'd be terminated right after testing the first condition.

Comment: The binding of sub-expressions to operators is, by definition, to do with precedence.

Comment: True that, "nothing to do with" is exaggerating. But the fact that expression is evaluated as $a && ($a = 1) rather than interpreting $a && $a as an lvalue isn't because of the operator precedence, but looks much more lika a 'fallback' in case lvalue is invalid.